# SQL query to get most recent row use asp.net+access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

select and get or retrieve a date from calendar control in ASP.Net to the table and select time from checkbox to the table.

output :: The most recent date and time is .....

table TEST

```
Date_From_Calendar   |  TIME        |
---------------------|--------------|
15/12/2014           | 09.00-12.00  |
18/12/2014           | 15.00-18.00  |
18/12/2014           | 15.00-18.00  |
19/12/2014           | 15.00-18.00  |
19/12/2014           | 12.00-15.00  |
19/12/2014           | 12.00-15.00  |
19/12/2014           | 12.00-15.00  |
19/12/2014           | 09.00-12.00  |
20/12/2014           | 09.00-12.00  |
24/12/2014           | 09.00-12.00  |
```

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you tried so far? Please post your code and your results along with errors, if any.

Comment: I will try harder.I greately appreciate your concern

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Date_From_Calendar , MAX(TIME) AS TIME
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Date_From_Calendar
```

Comment: a little bit of googling would have saved you all that time you spent to post this question :)